# My custom hook is getting " not a function or its return value is not iterable" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my custom hook where I manipulate my local storage

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setTaskSubmissions } from '../redux/actions/main';

function useLocalStorageHandler({setTaskSubmissions}, key, defaultValue = '') {

    const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => window.localStorage.getItem(key) || defaultValue)
    const prevKeyRef = React.useRef(key);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const prevKey = prevKeyRef.current;
        if (prevKey !== key) {
            window.localStorage.removeItem(prevKey)
        }
        prevKeyRef.current = key
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, state)
    }, [key, state])

    return [state, setState]
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { taskSubmissions: state.main.taskSubmissions }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    setTaskSubmissions
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(useLocalStorageHandler);
```

I am using the custom hook useLocalStorageHandler in this Submission component, where I have my initialValue declared

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useLocalStorageHandler } from '../../../hooks/useLocalStorageHandler';

const Submission = ({ initialValue = '' }) => {

const [name, setName] = useLocalStorageHandler('changing the name', initialValue);

   return (
    <div>...
</div>)

export default Submission;
```

Inspite of having my curly braces in place i am facing this TypeError,

**TypeError: (0 , *hooks_useLocalStorageHandler__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15*_.useLocalStorageHandler) is not a function or its return value is not iterable**

Comment: can you move () => window.localStorage.getItem(key) || defaultValue inside the useEffect, looks like useState is storing a function

Comment: export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(useLocalStorageHandler); can you call the custom hook directly in the component and use a hook to get current state and function